# How can I map an Array or an Object to an Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Normally a **map** method returns an Array but I have had a lot use-cases where I would like to create an Object instead. Is there a JavaScript native way of doing this or a very simple and performant implementation? jQuery solutions are also welcome.

This is how the native Array map method works (EcmaScript 6):

```
console.log( [ 1, 2, 4 ].map( item => item * 10) );
// => [ 10, 20, 40 ]
```

This is how I imagine the method to work (in case it is JavaScript native):

```
console.log( [ 1, 2, 4 ].mapToObject(resolveMultiplyWithTen) );
// => { 1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 40 }
```

In this example, the method **mapToObject** should behave the same like **map** but return an Object instead of an Array. Callback **resolveMultiplyWithTen** would multiply the item with ten.

A problem which I see here is that the callback function can not return two values (key and value, e.g.: 1 and 20), which would be needed to efficiently create an Object.

This is how I always used to create an Object from Array:

```
/* Loop over Array and create key:value pairs in Object */
const arr = [ 1, 2, 4];
const obj = {};
for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
  obj[arr[i]] = arr[i] * 10;
console.log(obj);
// => { 1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 40 }
```

This is the most suiting solution I could think of:

```
/* Create an Object of each item via map and apply to Object.assign */
console.log(Object.assign.apply(null, [ 1, 2, 4 ].map( item => {
  const out = {};
  out[item] = item * 10;
  return out;
})));
// => { 1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 40 }
```

Is there any native JavaScript solution to this problem or a more performant way?

Comment: Given an array of `[1, 2, 3]`, what exactly would the keys be for the values?

Comment: You can use the Array.prototype.reduce to convert an array to an object.  You just have to define how the keys and values should be defined.

Comment: `I have had a lot use-cases where I would like to create an Object instead` I question those use-cases.

Comment: @James Let's say you have an Object and want to modify the keys/values recursively (to a new Object). In my understanding this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let obj = [ 1, 2, 4 ].reduce( (op,inp) => (op[inp] = inp * 10, op),{} )

console.log(obj)
```

or you can use `forEach`

```js
let data = [ 1, 2, 4 ]
let obj = {}

data.forEach(val=>{
  obj[val] = val * 10
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `reduce()`

```js
let res = [ 1, 2, 4 ].reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a] = a * 10,ac),{})
console.log(res)
```

Or you can also use `Object.fromEntries`

```js
let res = Object.fromEntries([ 1, 2, 4 ].map(x => [x, x * 10]))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly and seems to be the most performant solution possible. Code Maniac was faster to provide the same answer, which is why I marked it as correct.

Comment: @BL4CKY No problem he was first to give `reduce()` version.